# Close menu on click outside - Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I created a side menu, which displays and hides when clicking the menu button. Now, I would like that the menu closes when I click outside the menu, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

I have tried adding a clicklistener to the body, but this disables the menu completely. I also thougt about getting the ID of the clicked element anywhere in the body and close the menu if `clickedElement != sideBar && sideBar.style = "200px"`, but I cannot get it to work. Can someone help me out here? I would like to find a solution without JQuery.

```
menuBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (sideBar.style.width == "200px") {
    sideBar.style.width = "0px";
    setTimeout(function () {
      menuItems.style.display = "none";
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    sideBar.style.width = "200px";
    menuItems.style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an event listener to the parent container and check if the click's target is inside the element or not, something like:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (box.contains(e.target)) {
    result.innerHTML = "inside";
  } else {
    result.innerHTML = "outside";
  }
});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: What about clicking child element in menu? It closes again. How can we prevent that?